# Sum a list of Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

In a dataframe I have 24-Columns: `h0, h1, ... h23`. I can sum them by `df['h0']+df['h1']+...+df['h23']`.

How can I do it with a loop?

Edit:

I forgot to say, that there are other columns than `h0, h1, ... h23`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df.sum(1)
```

to sum along the rows on all columns. Or if you have a sublist of columns `col_list = ['h0', 'h2', 'h3', 'h23']`:

```
df[col_list].sum(1)
```

Comment: better close...

Comment: then the answer is: df[{"h"+str(h) for h in range(0,24)}].sum(1)

Comment: I feel safer using list `df[[f'h{i}' for i in range(24)]].sum(1)`. But if set works for you, go for it.

Comment: Google tells me, this is called f-Strings. I will take a look to it. Thank you.